Zodライブラリで型を作成したのだが思った挙動と異なる。
Zodライブラリ(https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod)で以下のようにバリデーションルールを作成し、それに基づく型を定義しました。
const hoge = z.object({
  hoge: z
    .union([z.enum(["a", "b", "c"]), z.literal("")]) // "a","b","c"もしくは ""(空文字)を許容する
    .refine((val) => val !== "", { message: "hoge" }), // 空文字の場合のバリデーションルール
});

export type SchemaHoge = z.infer<typeof hoge>;

SchemaHoge の型は
{
    hoge: "a" | "b" | "c" | "";
}

となって欲しいのですが、実際には空文字("")が型の中に含まれていません。
refineメソッドを削除すると正しい挙動になるのですが、実装先では空文字に対してバリデーションメッセージを表示させたいのでrefineメソッドを削除することはできません。
どうすればrefineメソッドを残しつつ、SchemaHogeの型に空文字を含ませることができるでしょうか。
以下はバージョン情報です。
{
 "zod": "^3.23.8"
 "react": "^18.3.1",
}

宜しくお願い致します。
